# Using FATE Core to play a TITANFALL storyline

Tags: homebrew, fate-core, fate-accelerated

Specifically I'm looking for any advice on adapting FATE (or any generic RPG system really but I own FATE) for Titan combat. Thank You!

Comment: This site isn't particularly good at broad "give me advice" questions, are there any concrete problems you've encountered while trying Titan combat in Fate, or anything specific you are unsure while work?

Comment: As Erik says, this question is likely to be closed as it lacks a clear answerable point. But now that you're here, take the [tour] to get a better grasp on how this site works. Perhaps you can make one or more better questions out of this one! And welcome to the site :)

Comment: How big are your Titans? 5, 20, 100 meters?

Comment: As a recommendation, you could ask how well suited Fate Core is to the playstyle you're seeking. If you're detailed enough, it will be answerable and our Fate experts will be glad to provide their views on the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I am brand new to RPGs so I'll do my best to narrow down my info request. First of all I would like to know if FATE would work for a Titanfall scenario or if another system would work better. For FATE, specifically, I would like to know if simply scaling players to Titans would suffice. Titans are described, in the video game, as being about 20-25 meters tall. Sorry for the noob questions :(

Comment: @Dubhlaoich It's ok, it happens to many people and isn't anything to be ashamed about. I think if you edit your question to be more precise you'll get it reopened! You could focus on, for instance, on describing what sort of game experience you want (eg. heavy on tactical combat, or more focused on interpersonal drama?) and then asking how Fate can handle it.'